# Opening new tab in the background

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I am trying to open a new tab in the background as on vouchercodes where you open the link and return to the previous tab. I have read this is not possible in Javascript. I am using JQuery mobile.

So far I have

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="window.open('http://google.com'); document.getElementById('show').style.display='';return false;"></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know, the new tab behaviour is a browser setting which is set by the user. You can't open an link in background with Javascript/jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 <a target="_blank" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="window.open('http://google.com'); document.getElementById('show').style.display='';return false;"></a>
```

But you can't go back from tab a to b impossible.